# Sybase stored procedure locked by user

Tags: sybase, locked

I've created a stored procedure, but I can't alter it now, because the darn thing is still in use.

```
alter proc GetDuplicates @search1 varchar(40) = '', @search2 varchar(40) = 
'blahblehblargh' as

select distinct i4202 "Man", i4203 "Mod"
    into #ManModTemp
    from inventory
    where i4211 like ('2%')
    order by i4202 desc

select distinct i4202 "Man", i4203 "Mod", count(*) "Count"
    into #ManModCount
    from inventory
    group by i4202, i4203

select Man, Mod
    into #ManModList
    from #ManModTemp
    where Mod in (select Mod from #ManModList group by Mod having Count(*) > 
    1) and (Man like '%' + IsNull(@search1,'') + '%' or Man like '%' + 
    IsNull(@search2, 'blahblehblargh') + '%')

select * from #ManModList
    join #ManModCount
    on (#ManModList.Man = #ManModCount.Man and #ManModList.Mod = 
    #ManModCount.Mod)
```

I think the mistake I made, maybe, is that I didn't wrap it in BEGIN-END statements and now it's just not ending?

Please forgive the hacky code (as my wife, the developer, calls it). I'm new at this?

Here is the error:

```
Could not execute statement.
Procedure in use by 'user'
SQLCODE=-215, ODBC 3 State="40001"
Line 1, column 1
```

Comment: Been a while since I used Sybase, and this might depend on your specific Sybase version, but I always had to drop and re-create stored procedures.

Comment: Are you using Sybase ASE?